# Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid in Bullseye

Tags: pigpio, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I recently moved from Buckeye to Bullseye. I can no longer execute programs that use pigpio. See interactions:

```
g2@raspberrypi:~ $ pigs t
socket connect failed
g2@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status pigpiod
 
● pigpiod.service - Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio

     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service; disabled; vendor pres>
     Active: inactive (dead)

[1]+  Stopped                 systemctl status pigpiod

g2@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo killall pigpiodc
pigpiodc: no process found

g2@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pigpiod 

g2@raspberrypi:~ $ pigs t


540712792

g2@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status pigpiod 

● pigpiod.service - Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio

     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service; disabled; vendor pres>
     Active: inactive (dead)

g2@raspberrypi:~/projects/pigpio1 $ sudo ./pigpio
gpio version 79 

2022-08-10 10:06:27 initInitialise: Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid
pigpio initialisation failed.

trying restart didn't help

sudo systemctl restart pigpiod

systemctl status pigpiod
 pigpiod.service - Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-08-10 10:48:22 EDT; 18s ago
    Process: 10709 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pigpiod -l (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 10710 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 15ms

Aug 10 10:48:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio...
Aug 10 10:48:22 raspberrypi pigpiod[10710]: 2022-08-10 10:48:22 initInitialise: Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid
Aug 10 10:48:22 raspberrypi pigpiod[10710]: Can't initialise pigpio library
Aug 10 10:48:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio.
Aug 10 10:48:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: pigpiod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 10 10:48:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: pigpiod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: What is in the file `./pigpio`? There is no program called `pigpiodc`.  The daemon is called `pigpiod`.

Comment: "I recently moved from Buckeye to Bullseye" what did you ACTUALLY do? Did you do a fresh install as recommended?